# How can I output a Column break character in C++

Tags: c++, ascii, special-characters, multiple-columns, utf

I currently have a vector of structs with "coord" having an x and y value.

```
std::vector<coord> Positions;
```

I would like to be able to print out the values in a way that I can directly copy them and paste them into Excel without having to use the 'Text Import wizard' each time.

This may sound lazy, however I also need to paste the data into another piece of software that will only split them into two columns if it is coming from excel. After a while this swapping back and forth is becoming laborious as I am making regular small tweaks to variables in my main algorithm.

I have tried printing the values with a tab separating them, but it still pastes it into excel as if it were just a longer space in only one column.

This is how I am currently printing the data:

```
for (a = 0; a < Positions.size(); a++)
{
    std::cout << Positions[a].x << "\t" << Positions[a].y << "\n";
}
```

I noticed that when I copy and paste data from two columns in excel, the tab is longer than a normal tab and I suspect that it is a special character which I can't seem to find. I also suspect this character is called a "Column Break".

I am unable to google the character, Even pasting it below shows a different character.

> "  "

Does any body know what this character is? If not, is there another method to print out data that is compatible with pasting into seperate excel columns?

UPDATE:
I have found the character in question, it is called ["SYMBOL FOR RECORD SEPARATOR"](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/241e/index.htm). I am still having trouble printing it, even using  `"\u241E"` as suggested by the website.

Comment: *I suspect that it is a special character which I can't seem to find* -- Why not print out the value of the character instead of what the character looks like visually?  Then you know exactly what to look for.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie It seems I forgot to mention that, I did try that to no avail.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie re-reading your comment I'm not entirely sure what you mean. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: All characters have a value.  For example, in ASCII, an `A` is 65, `0` is 48, etc.  Print the value of that character you are not sure of.

Comment: Isn't this more a question about how to use Excel than C++? Also, does this help: https://www.wikihow.com/Copy-Paste-Tab-Delimited-Text-Into-Excel

Comment: @jogojapan I know how to paste delimited text into excel, the excel side is not an issue for me,  I am trying to figure out how to ouput that specific character in cpp, I thought that perhaps there was a escapable character that I could print.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I can't figure out what the ASCII value is

Comment: `std::cout << (int)Positions[a].x << "\t" << (int)Positions[a].y << "\n";`

Comment: If the information on the wikihow page is correct, you don't need to figure out that character. You can just use tab, and if that doesn't work follow the steps on that page to make it work. (I don't have Excel to hand so I can test it.)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie That does not output the same character, I have the same line in my question.

Comment: @jogojapan I said that I know how to import delimited text, following the steps on the page I could use any character I like, But I specifically would like to find that character, it is like an extended tab.

Comment: @ONTHISTING *Even pasting it below shows a different character.* -- This is what is confusing.  You have the character to "paste".  Where did you get it from? Did you get it programatically?  If you have the character in the clipboard to paste, then paste it somewhere where you don't lose the value of that character, not in the StackOverflow edit window.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I copied a excel table to notepad, I then copied the character from notepad to visual studio and the edit window, the character doesnt copy

Comment: Too many hops.  Take what you copied, paste it from the clipboard in a hex editor and inspect the value of that character.  I use [XVI](http://www.chmaas.handshake.de/delphi/freeware/xvi32/xvi32.htm)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Read my edit, I found the character in question, I am now having trouble printing it. I must sleep now but I will look into this properly tomorrow.

Comment: So the question has shifted to "how to print Unicode characters".  There should be many links as to how to do that.